# customize the tablesorter arrow image

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am working with the jQuery tablesorter. I I want  to replace  the default arrow image with my own arrow image. I added the

```
.tablesorter-default thead .headerSortUp,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerSortUp,
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-headerAsc {
    background-image: url( My image );
    border-bottom: #000 5px solid;
}
```

Here I tried the with the border as 5px. But this change is not reflected in my UI. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I am trying to change the border-bottom to 5px . Even this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does work, but you might be missing the part where the `theme` option isn't changed from `"default"` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1246/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'default'
});
```

But, it might be better to just make that css more general, unless you want to change the image or border color on sorting ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1245/)):

```
.tablesorter-default thead .tablesorter-header {
    background-image: url( My image );
    border-bottom: #000 5px solid;
}
```